# SharePoint design manager: how to insert a RichHtmlField?

Tags: sharepoint-2013

I have created a site column of type **Multiple lines of text** and added it to a content type.
I have then created a page layout with the design manager using this content type.

The field inserted in the page layout is always a **NoteField** but I would like a **RichHtmlField**.

I don't know how to configure the field in the Snippet Gallery.

I have tried to specified the type of text to allow for the site column:

- Rich text (Bold, italics, text alignment, hyperlinks)
- Enhanced rich text (Rich text with pictures, tables, and hyperlinks)

It doesn't matter what I choose, I always end up with a NoteField.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, instead of choosing a site column of type **Multiple lines of text**, choosing the type **Publishing HTML** (Full HTML content with formatting and constraints for publishing) brings the rich editor needed. Still seems weird though.